# Spring Boot 1.5 validated ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring-boot

Jump to the bottom for the motivations and the solutions to this issue!

In the process of upgrading from Spring Boot `1.4` to `1.5` I read (source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.5-Release-Notes#upgrading-from-spring-boot-14)

> If you have @ConfigurationProperties classes that use JSR-303 constraint annotations, you should now additionally annotate them with @Validated. Existing validation will currently continue to work, however, a warning will be logged. In the future, classes without @Validated will not be validated at all.

So, diligently, I add `@Validated` to all of mine configuration properties. Now I have a specific use case that breaks, aka the property is not loaded anymore (I summarize first, then add code).

If I use a template property defined in `application.properties` file and then try to override the value for specific profiles, then the application is not starting.

Here is some sample code to reproduce (relevant files):

`build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

`application.properties` : `demo.prop=${profile.prop}`

`application-demo.properties` : `profile.prop=demo`

`DemoApplication.java`

```
package package;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
    public static class RestController {

        @Autowired
        private DemoProperties properties;

        @GetMapping
        public String get() {
            return properties.prop == null ? "null" : properties.prop;
        }
    }

    @Component
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "demo")
//  @Validated
    public static class DemoProperties {

        @NotNull
        private String prop;

        public void setProp(String prop) {
            this.prop = prop;
        }

        public String getProp() {
            return prop;
        }
    }
}
```

As it stands, my application produces the expected result when run with `-Dspring.profiles.active=demo`

```
curl "http://localhost:8080"
demo
```

however, uncommenting `//@validated` and running the application as before produces

```
curl "http://localhost:8080"
null
```

Full application available at https://github.com/ThanksForAllTheFish/boot-props (including a test case showing that defining `profile.prop` in `config/application.properties` fails as well with `@validated` but succeeds without).

I guess it is a bug in Spring Boot, but it may me not understanding something, so SoF first (as hinted in Spring Boot issues manager on github).

This github issue seems related: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8173

Comment: I actually made the use case more convoluted that it had to be. Just have application.properties with demo.prop=prop as single line content is enough to see the same issue. I updated the github repo

Comment: You haven't included a validator and hence nothing will be validated. Also overriding properties like that isn't going work. It isn't a multi pass process everything is read and then processed... So only specifying it as a system property, environment property or startup parameter will make it override

Comment: @M.Deinum, not true, as I wrote, if I remove `@Validated` the application behaves as expected. I am surprised as well I don't need a validator, but if I empty my application.properties file I get a BindException

Comment: (`Caused by: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder$RelaxedBeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'demo' on field 'prop': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.demo.prop,NotNull.prop,NotNull.java.lang.String,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [demo.prop,prop]; arguments []; default message [prop]]; default message [may not be null]`) which imo is enough to show the validation takes place

Comment: Hmm ... Apparently the validator is default part of the web starter (thought it was optional). I still don't get what is wrong with what you describe (you don't specify a profile and the property is `null` which is correct imho as you haven't specified it otherwise.

Comment: I wrote Run with `-Dspring.profiles.active=demo`, just under all the source code. I understand it is quite a long post, maybe just clone the repo and see with your own eyes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I found the solution to my issue (some time ago already, but added as explanation in the question itself), I figured it may be more helpful to copy my findings here.

The problem with my sample code is that `@Validated` wraps the real class with a proxy, so that validation concerns can be injected, therefore return `properties.prop == null ? "null" : properties.prop;` is actually trying to access the `prop` field of the proxy. Changing to getProp() is the fix. Pretty obvious once found out.

Regarding production code: the issue was related to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8173, or more precisely to https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/177, as we use spring-cloud. Basically, there was a conflict in `BeanPostProcessor` between `spring-cloud` and `spring-boot` (details in the ticket on github) that was solved in `Dalston.RELEASE` of `spring-cloud`. Just updating the dependency in our project solved the issue in production as well. Lot of digging and testing to just change 7 characters in our codebase.